# XML - parsing file returns NULL

Tags: c, xml, xml-parsing

Yesterday I could parse XML files with a program written in C, using the function
`doc = xmlParseFile(fname);`.

Now, it returns NULL (which gets caught on the next line, returning an error). The program hasn't been changed for over a month, the XML files haven't changed since last week and libxml2 hasn't changed since the 25.3.2012. xmllint runs through the files with no problem, and I can parse them on another computer (Solaris, using the same source code, but a different compiler and library). So what else should I check? It sounds similar to this thread, although I'd like to avoid that hacky solution http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1402824 (haven't tried it yet)

The C program is actually a mex function called from MatLab, but that shouldn't make any difference, right? I am running this on GNU/Linux.

Comment: You should make it more clear what xml library you are using.

Comment: It's on a cluster, so I don't have admin rights, but the name is /usr/lib64/libxml2.so.2.7.6 (or libxml2.a or libxml2.la). It's a 64 bit machine, hence the lib64. Does that answer your question?

Comment: have you compiled and linked against the appropriate 64bit libraries? (libc, libm and so on)

Comment: I guess so, seeing as it worked up until today. I use this command to compile:
matlab_2011b/bin/mex -DDEBUG -I/usr/lib64 -lxml2 my_parse_xml.c
there is a libc.a and libm.a inside /usr/lib64

Comment: erm... it's fixed now, after trying Peter's suggestion unsuccessfully and then removing it. Thanks for the suggestions, and sorry for the bother. I guess the admins were messing with stuff.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
  FILE *f = fopen("~/myxml.log", "a");
  xmlSetGenericErrorFunc(f, NULL);
  doc = xmlParseFile(fname);
  fclose(f);
```

and look on the results in the log-file.

Comment: good idea, but I couldn't open the file. (f==NULL after the fopen call.) Any idea why? Permissions were 666.

Comment: that depends on your operating system. under windows it may be "c:\myxml.log". under UNIX "~" expands to your "$HOME", maybe that is not set. You can try "/home/craq/myxml.log" or whereever you reside.